# Embedding XSLT in the XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's suppose we have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="class.xsl"?>
<class>
    <student>Jack</student>
    <student>Harry</student>
    <student>Rebecca</student>
    <teacher>Mr. Bean</teacher>
</class>
```

This file would render nicely in a browser with a proper `class.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html><body>
  <ol>
    <xsl:for-each select="class/student">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ol>
  </body></html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there a way to include the content of `class.xsl` in the same XML file, so that the file `class.xsl` does not exist?

I know this is possible with a CSS stylesheet, normally referred by `<link>`, can also be nested in.

---

**Edit**: I experimented with referencing the same XML file as the stylesheet, however, XSLT's `<stylesheet>` does not function if not used as the root element.

Is it possible to allow `class.xsl` to source some XSLT segment defined in the XML file and use it as XSLT? This would allow a generic XSLT file to be defined to load XSLT rules from each individual XML file.

Comment: Are you asking for something like https://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/Overview-tech.html#self-style ?

Comment: @Vebbie I believe so! I would really appreciate you answer the question by using the source material I provided `class.xml` and `class.xsl`, that is, how the merged XML is like. I struggled to follow the instructions you linked and ended up with a mess. Your answer would benefit others too.

Comment: I believe the closest you can get is an [embedded stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Embedding-Stylesheets).  Compare also to a [simplified stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#result-element-stylesheet) (which is the basis for the article linked above).

Comment: See also the example here: https://calebmadrigal.com/embedding-xslt-xml-document/

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#ssid"?>
<xx>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" id="ssid" xml:id="ssid"
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <html><body>
    <ol>
    <xsl:for-each select="//class/student">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </ol>
   </body></html>
  </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
 <class>
    <student>Jack</student>
    <student>Harry</student>
    <student>Rebecca</student>
    <teacher>Mr. Bean</teacher>
 </class>
</xx>
```

I don't know how well-supported this is in browsers. According to comments on this answer, Chrome needs the `xml:id` attribute while Firefox needs the `id` attribute to recognize the fragment identifier `#ssid`.

Comment: I believe you need to have an `id` attribute on `xsl:stylesheet` to match the one declared in the prolog. I don't think it can work without it - however, I don't know it that's enough.

Comment: Yes thanks, I thought I had added it, but it somehow slipped away!

Comment: Should it be `xml:id` or `id`? I tested both. Firefox won't accept `xml:id` and Google Chrome won't accept `id`.

Comment: @MichaelKay would you kindly update your example to use both `id="id"` and `xml:id="id"` then it would work for both Chrome and Firefox. I'll mark yours as the right answer accordingly.